# Python 3 OOPS Inheritnce

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I tried to write two classes, but i got attribute error

```
class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self._data = []

    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self._data)==0

    def push(self,e):
        return self._data.append(e)

    def pop(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise Exception('Stack is Empty')
        return self._data.pop()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)
class para_checker(Stack):

    def __init__(self,string):

        super(Stack).__init()
        self.string = string



    def basic_checker(self):
        balanced = True
        index = 0
        while index < len(self.string) and balanced :
            s = self.string[index]
            if s =='(':
                super.push(s)
            else:
                if super.is_empty():
                    balanced = False
                else:
                    super.pop()
        if balanced and super.is_empty():
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I want to create a object of child class and access parachecker method on that also want to learn ds algo using python

Comment: What is the error? Please see [ask].

Comment: You are calling `__init()` not `__init__()`, and you aren't calling `super` on `self`

Comment: maybe let the checker class have-a stack (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a) as opposed to be is-a stack (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `__init`, not `__init__`, and you are calling `super` on the wrong object.

```py
class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self._data = []

    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self._data)==0

    def push(self,e):
        return self._data.append(e)

    def pop(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise Exception('Stack is Empty')
        return self._data.pop()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)
class para_checker(Stack):

    def __init__(self,string):

        super(para_checker, self).__init__()
        self.string = string



    def basic_checker(self):
        balanced = True
        index = 0
        while index < len(self.string) and balanced :
            s = self.string[index]
            if s =='(':
                super.push(s)
            else:
                if super.is_empty():
                    balanced = False
                else:
                    super.pop()
        if balanced and super.is_empty():
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: One-argument calls to `super` need to be a type.  In this case, that type would be `para_checker`, which would be the type we're trying to resolve an MRO for.  The two argument version would be `super(para_checker, self)`.  Using Python 3, if you're inside a class definition, you can omit both arguments `super()`, which is equivalent to the two argument version.